# Split "first,middle,middle,last" into array with 3 elements (first, middle, last)

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I'd like to split the following string into three elements:

```
first, middle, middle, middle, middle, last
```

So the result would be:

```
splits[0] = "first"
splits[1] = "middle, middle, middle, middle"
splits[2] = "last"
```

I don't know if this is best done by regex or string methods.

Comment: what about if,"first,first,first", Is this all are in [0]th.

Comment: My problem relates to the ","'s rather than the content of the string. "first, first, first" would become [0] = "first" [1] = "first" [2] = "first"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var s = "first, middle, middle, middle, middle, last";
var singleItems = s.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim());
var splits = new []
             {
                 singleItems.Take(1).Single(),
                 singleItems.Skip(1).Take(singleItems.Count() - 2)
                                    .Aggregate("", (s1, s2) => s1 + s2 + ", ")
                                    .Trim(' ', ','),
                 singleItems.Skip(singleItems.Count() - 1).Single()
             };
```

An alternative way of doing it would be this:

```
var firstIndex = s.IndexOf(',');
var lastIndex = s.LastIndexOf(',');
var splits = new []
             {
                 s.Substring(0, firstIndex),
                 s.Substring(firstIndex + 2, lastIndex - (firstIndex + 2)),
                 s.Substring(lastIndex + 2)
             };
```

I think the second solution is cleaner and easier to understand. But it has the disadvantage that the first and the last comma must be followed by a space. This requirement does not exist for the first version.

Comment: Upvote for the nice approach! Just that I think the aggregate won't give him the middle names in the requested way (middle,[comma] [space]middle).

Comment: Thank you, with some trimming and substrings, that solved it for me!

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, I saw that. I really like your solution. This is how code should look like.

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
var input = "first, middle, middle, middle, middle, last";


var outputs = input.Split(',').Select(wrd=>wrd.Trim())
                              .GroupBy(wrd=>wrd)
                              .Select(lst => string.Join(", ", lst)).ToArray();
```

output[0] = "first" 
  output[1] = "middle, middle, middle, middle" 
  output[2] = "last"

The **Select(...Trim())**  removes the leading spaces after the split. 
The **GroupBy(...)** gives three lists ({"first"}, {"middle", "middle", "middle", "middle"}, {"last"}
The **Select(...Join(...))**  creates the final strings with the correct commas.

hth, 
Alan.

Comment: @insta Thanks, I sorta liked it too :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  string separator = ", ";
  string input = "first, middle, middle, middle, middle, last";
  int i1 = input.IndexOf(separator);
  int i2 = input.LastIndexOf(separator);
  string[] splits = new string[3];
  splits[0] = input.Substring(0, i1);
  splits[1] = input.Substring(i1 + separator.Length, i2 - i1 - separator.Length);
  splits[2] = input.Substring(i2 + separator.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string data = "first, middle, middle, middle, middle, last";

string[] splitData = data.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

Dictionary<string, string> splits = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (var s in splitData)
{
    var temp = s.Trim();
    if (splits.ContainsKey(temp))
    {
        splits[temp] += ", " + temp;
    }
    else
    {
        splits[temp] = temp;
    }
}

string[] result = splits.Select(y => y.Value).ToArray();
```